# Load databases from PostgreSQL server to Apache Druid

Tags: database, postgresql, migration, database-migration, druid

I have a postgreSQL cluster that has a lot of databases inside it and
I want to migrate all of these databases to Apache Druid, is there any one who can help me ?
Thanks in advance

I have searched a lot but for I didn't find any useful information

Answer (score 0):

You can use batch ingestion tasks to extract data directly from postgreSQL. [SQL Based ingestion](https://druid.apache.org/docs/24.0.0/multi-stage-query/index.html) is likely your best path. You can use the [EXTERN table function](https://druid.apache.org/docs/24.0.0/multi-stage-query/reference.html#extern) to [access PostgreSQL using SQL](https://druid.apache.org/docs/24.0.0/ingestion/native-batch-input-sources.html#sql-input-source) statements. You can use multiple SQL statements for different portions of the data in order to increase parallelism.

That said, it is likely that you will need to model the data different in Druid. While Druid is capable of doing joins, that is typically reserved for quick lookups, not for complex multi-table joins. In order to deliver fast response times, Druid data modeling usually involves flattening data.
Here is a great course on [Data Modeling in Druid](https://learn.imply.io/apache-druid-ingestion-and-data-modeling).